# Swift: After update to 4.2 can not extend Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift4, swift4.2

Before update to Swift 4.2 I had next Dictionary extension:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func someKey(forValue val: Value) -> Key? {
        return first(where: { $1 == val })?.key
    }

}
```

And use it in `[String:String]` dictionary.

[image]

[image]

After update to 4.2 it is failed in compilation with: no such method exists

Are there changes in Dictionary definition in 4.2?

Comment: It compiles fine.

Comment: @alexBerd This code run fine on swift 4.2 Kindly correct.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh. I added some pictures to review

Comment: @AlexBerd May be there is something wrong with auto complete. Try to call manually like this: `languages.someKey(forValue: "en-US")`. Try cleaning and quitting and restarting Xcode.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh I cleaned project, deleted derived data, reopen xcode. Nothing happens :((((. Thanks for help. I will write this func as open func and not in extension

Comment: The code works fine for me in 4.2. Did you put the extension in a different module and forget to import it? Is there some error somewhere else that prevents the extension from compiling? Is the error in a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't added the file where your extension is located properly to your project.

Go to your project Targets > Build Phases > Compile Sources and check if your Swift file that contains your dictionary extension is listed there, if not click the plus sign and add it. After that you should be able to use your extension methods anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 0):

@Leo Dabus was right in it s comment. For some reason the extension file was not in my compile sources.

[image]

When I add it to the compile source all is working fine

Comment: I wonder why someone would vote this down. If you would like to I can post my comment as an answer and you can delete yours.